# How do I identify particularly rare columns of values

Tags: r, statistical-significance

I am brainstorming ideas on how to identify the rarest columns of values, from a large df.

The context of the issue is that the columns represent different samples, and the rows are genomic regions. In some samples, the values of the genomic regions may be lower, and in others they may be higher, but generally the majority of samples should have similar values across the genomic region.

df setup - with four columns which are clear outliers (two which could indicate a deletion in the regions, and two which indicate duplications in the regions).

```
set.seed(42)
toy <- data.frame(replicate(50,sample(0:100,5,rep=TRUE)))
toy[,1] <- toy[,1] / 4
toy[,2] <- toy[,2] * 4
toy[,3] <- toy[,3] / 6
toy[,4] <- toy[,4] * 6
colMeans(toy)
```

I am looking for ideas on how to identify columns like `toy[,1]` or `toy[,3]` as particularly low in contrast to all other samples, or `toy[,2]` or `toy[,4]` as particularly high in contrast to all other samples.

I attempted to use the mean of each column to identify which columns are above or below the the 90% and 10% range - which does answer my query, but would be interested in exploring more robust statistical methods.

```
toy[6,] <- colMeans(toy)
q <- quantile(toy[,6], probs = c(.1, .9))
which(toy[6,] < q[1])
[1]  1  3 11
which(toy[6,] > q[2])
[1] 2 4
```

Comment: Welcome to CV.   Could you please tell us what you might mean by "rarity" of a column of values?  This doesn't appear to be a standard term in statistics.  Indeed, it's unclear what you might mean by "particularly low" or "particularly high:" compared to what, in what sense?

Comment: Thank you @whuber, I have updated the question to reflect better what I meant

Comment: Why not just use an ANOVA?